# Creating table to count number of transaction done by each position

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have an `employee` table with columns

```
 employee_ID, employee_name, employee_DOB, emp_Email, Emp_Phone, Emp_Position
```

and a `transaction` table with columns

```
transaction_ID, employee_ID, distribution_ID, Invoice_Number, transaction_Date
```

I want to show these columns using a SQL query:

```
Emp_Position, Transaction_done
```

`Transaction_done` is a number consisting of how many transactions employees in each position has done.

I've tried to use `select count(transaction_ID)` but it didn't show a correct count.

Comment: Please show us the table structure (**data types** of those columns), your query used and the input data in the table that produces the "wrong" result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Emp_Position
      ,count(transaction_ID) 
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN [transaction] t
    ON e.[employee_ID] = t.[employee_ID]
GROUP BY Emp_Position;
```